# SpaCy can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to train a text categorization pipe in SpaCy:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.add_pipe("textcat", last=True)
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'textcat']
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    # training logic
```

However, every time I call `nlp.begin_training()`, I get the error

```
ValueError: [E955] Can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data. Make sure you have the package installed or provide your own lookup tables if no default lookups are available for your language.
```

Running `python3 -m spacy validate` returns

```
✔ Loaded compatibility table

================= Installed pipeline packages (spaCy v3.0.3) =================
ℹ spaCy installation:
/xxx/xxx/xxx/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy

NAME             SPACY            VERSION                            
en_core_web_lg   >=3.0.0,<3.1.0   3.0.0   ✔
en_core_web_sm   >=3.0.0,<3.1.0   3.0.0   ✔
```

Furthermore, I have tried installing `spacy-lookups-data` without success.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It isn't allowed to call `nlp.begin_training()` on pretrained models. If you want to train a new model, just use:
`nlp = spacy.blank('en')`
instead of `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`

However, if you want to continue training on an existing model call `optimizer = nlp.create_optimizer()` instead of `begin_training()`

Comment: Bless you for this response.